# get bigquery results from node.js to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

I'm running a google compute engine with node.js **but am testing using codeanywhere**. I am able to run a bigquery request on codeanywhere terminal and get results to display on the terminal console.

but when I try to do the same from an html page, I can't quite get the results to return to the user/browser.

the only node modules I have installed on codeanywhere are firebase and googleapis.

I wish to run the bigquery call on the server side because I want to keep the auth information hidden; otherwise would simply run bigquery api from javascript.

my test.js is:

```
'use strict';

var google = require('XXX/lib/googleapis');
var bigquery = google.bigquery('v2');
var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    'XXX@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    'XXX.pem',
    null, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery']);

var request = {
    projectId: 'XXX',
    //all: true,

    auth: authClient
};

var list = bigquery.datasets.list(request, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
});
```

and my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">

    <head>
    <title>Testing Server Call </title> 
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> 
    <script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'test.js'
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('yay');
                console.log(data);              
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
            }
        });


    });

</script> 
</head>
<body>
    hi there

</body>
</html>
```

I've searched and tested for last couple days and have no idea what I am missing. I keep getting errors like: `Error: require is not defined` and I can't find any tutorials to help me through the steps to get this accomplished. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you try keeping the require statement before "use strict" ?

Comment: thank you. tried that, still get the error 'require is not defined'

Comment: @jm93 are you getting require error in browser or node console?

Comment: @owaishanif786 node console works fine, error is in browser, thx

Comment: require will never ever work in browser. so you have to use node.js console. to run it to use require in browser eithier you have to use http://browserify.org/ or webpack.

Comment: I don't understand. the 'require' is on the server code test.js not the browser. I'll check out the browserify, first time I've heard about that.

Comment: thanks, looks like browserify runs on server - how does that help this situation? if 'require' is on server along with browserify, how does that help the call from the browser that gets error from 'require'?

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var google = require('XXX/lib/googleapis');
var bigquery = google.bigquery('v2');
var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    'XXX@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    'XXX.pem',
    null, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery']);

var request = {
    projectId: 'XXX',
    //all: true,

    auth: authClient
};



var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var list = bigquery.datasets.list(request, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            response.end(result);
        }
    });
});
server.listen(8080, function(){});
```

At frontend you have to specify route where you will make request

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">

    <head>
    <title>Testing Server Call </title> 
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> 
    <script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/'
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('yay');
                console.log(data);              
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
            }
        });


    });

</script> 
</head>
<body>
    hi there

</body>
</html>
```

After that you have to just run at commandline  `node test.js`

Comment: thank you for quick assistance! i am currently testing. i did forget to mention my production side is google compute engine but am testing using codeanywhere workspace. hope that won't matter

Comment: unfortunately still getting the 'Error: require is not defined' in browser console, to be specific. and if I use http://localhost:8080/ as the route, I get 'connection refused' - this is using codeanywhere as my test environment

Comment: thank you, tried the edited code from the answer. same error. guess this is impossible. thank you for the help. looks I have to pay someone because stackoverflow not really designed for the help I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using test.js as url which is loading js on client side. You cannot use require on client side and so is this error. You should create a route and give it there.

Comment: that's what is partly confusing me. the test.js is on server so why is it "loading" in client? test.js works fine in terminal, but getting the data to the browser is what's killing me. no idea what I am missing.

Comment: The ajax call you wrote is equivalent to jQuery.getScript(); It is meant for loading script on client side.

Comment: what might be equivalent syntax that could work? i just want to get the bigquery result on the server side and send to the browser.

Comment: You will have to what @owaisshahhanif786 has suggested. Ajax call will be having a route. And on your system node server should be started by typing node test.js to get the server up on local.  Connection refuse error could come when your node server is not started.

Comment: thank you. I ran 'node test.js' again in the terminal. I get the server console message in the terminal, but when I refresh the html page, still get connection refused.